# Database connection error on cpanel

Tags: php, mysql

This code is working on my local server but it's not working on cpanel.

```
mysql_connect("localhost","hidigits_bodyfle","B!ZrgPr#Ic0g");
mysql_select_db("hidigits_bodyfle") or die('could not connect');
```

Comment: could you please help me fix this problem.

Comment: Could you read my comment and let us know what the problem is?

Comment: I am getting the msg could not connect  after giving this connection on my cpanel.

Comment: Great, that's a start, but that's still lacking quite a bit of info. Post the error that it outputs in your question...

Comment: Try `mysql_connect("localhost","hidigits_bodyfle","B!ZrgPr#Ic0g") or die(mysql_error()); mysql_select_db("hidigits_bodyfle") or die(mysql_error());` and that will give you a clue.

Comment: The out i am getting after giving the connection is "could not connect". But the same code is running on my local server.

Comment: Access denied for user 'hidigits_bodyfle'@'localhost' to database 'hidigits_bodyfle'.

Comment: Pretty self explanatory isn't it, you haven't put the right username and password in or haven't given the user access to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But there was a permission issue. Thanks for your valuable time

Answer (score -1):

May be The simplest , but a better procedure is:
Include this code in your php tags or you can either write a seperate file (for e.g. connect.inc.php) and include it in your page with the help of `include 'connect.inc.php';`

```
 $mysql_host = 'localhost';
 $mysql_user = 'username';
 $mysql_password = 'Desired password';
 $mysql_db = 'database_name';
 if( !mysql_connect ($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password ) || !mysql_select_db($mysql_db)){
   die (mysql_error());
 }
```

Comment: its a cpanel not localhost, so there must be password

Comment: Obviously , that's y i left a blank previously